# How to upload back-end to the hosting with database?

Tags: node.js, phpmyadmin, ftp, hosting, dreamhost

I have never did back-end with upload that's why I am asking.

So I have build my project in a folder *"Pro"* where I have one folder named *"Web"* which contains `React.js` application, and other folder named *"Server"* which has all info about server and database written with `Node.js`. I have achieved to run this project locally, but I do not know how to upload it online. About *"Web"* - I can do that easily, just by running `npm run-script build` I can upload then build folder to the FTP panel.

**First question:**

What about server side? How should I upload it? Also, buy running `npm run-script build` and putting it in the same folder online? It will create two files and folders with the same name?

**Second question:**

Locally, I was connecting to MySQL like this:

```
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())

// MySQL
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    user: "root",
    host: 'localhost,
    password: "",
    database: "mydatabase"
})
```

What should I change inside of it so it will work online? My database name online is *"database.myqsl"*, should I put *http://* in front of it? I literally know nothing.
I use *DreamHost* with *PHPMyAdmin* and *MySQL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, here is the solution:
You don't need additional service for that, `DreamHost` can handle the `Node.js`. For calling the API you will need additional domain, it can be a subdomain of your website. After creating a subdomain on the DreamHost, go to `Manage Domains` -> `"Edit" under the Web Hosting Column` -> `under the Web Options chek both "Passenger" and "Node.js"` and save it. You **don't need** to `npm run-script build` anything, it won't work anyway. After that upload all your files of the folder where you run your Node.js into the FTP **outside** of `/public` folder. And then, just call your api's like this on front-end: `Axios.get('https://server.yourdomain.com/login')` or whichever API call you use and it works perfectly. Also make sure that both of your front-end and back-end domain are `https secure`.

Articles for you to help:

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216635318-How-to-enable-Node-js

Also, my app.js' SQL connection looks like this:

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    user: "myuser",
    host: 'mysql.site.us',
    password: "site_us_pass",
    database: "db_us"
})
```